# How to get type of chrome tab changeInfo?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, listener

Hello I want my chrome extension to detect when a tab's title changes.

I'm using the

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    //code goes here
}
```

function which works but gets change info for every type of change (url change, icon change, title change, etc). So I'm trying to find a way to determine what type of change is occurring with the changeInfo variable.

You can see in this picture below some of the different values the changeInfo array can take:
[image]

**Is there a way to call 'changeInfo.type' or something and get the type of change? (status, favIconUrl, title, etc)**

I've tried finding this string value by printing things like changeInfo.type, changeInfo.id, and looked through the documentation:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs (ctrl+f "onUpdated")

But I cant seem to find this info. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no given `type` and `id` attribute in [`changeInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) object as I have checked the documentation. You can try to file a feature request and follow the steps from this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/faq#faq-fea-02).

Comment: I figured out a workaround, if I call " changeInfo['title'] ", it will return the string title for a title change, and return undefined for any other type of change

Comment: That's great. Sorry if my answer didn't help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a truthy comparison on the info object:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.title) {
        // your code here...
    }
}
```